# How to multiply a random time from milliseconds to minutes and seconds?

Tags: javascript

Hi so I was wondering how I might multiply a song time that is random since it is a song which changes every song. I am trying to change it from milliseconds which it is at at the moment to minutes and seconds in javascript.

Comment: Your question is too broad - you need to narrow the scope of what you're trying to achieve. Otherwise the obvious answer is, divide by 1000 once for seconds, and then divide by (1000 * 60) for minutes

Comment: Fourth grade arithmetic. How many milliseconds are in a second? How many seconds are in a minute?